# A more efficient way to match values from different keys of JSON objects - find Twitter "conversations

Tags: python, json, twitter, match

I have large JSON files containing data from Twitter in the following format (I've removed many of the Tweet properties for ease of reading):

```
{u'user': {
    u'id': 377881302, 
    u'name': u'kenji '}, 
 u'text': u'@mochan_s2 \u4ffa\u306f\u3001',        
 u'in_reply_to_status_id_str': u'288112458336456704',  
 u'id_str':  u'288120868188602368'
}

{u'user': {
    u'id': 377881302, 
    u'name': ... }
...
}
...
```

There are hundreds of thousands of Tweets in each JSON file.

I am trying to create from this a corpus of Twitter conversations, where all the Tweets from the same thread are stored together.

In order to do this I need to match any Tweet that has an `in_reply_to_status_id` with the original Tweet that has that `id_str` number.

Using jq I have extracted all the id_str and in_reply_to_id_str values and then found the set of these i.e. all values that appear in the data as *both* `id_str` and `in_reply_to_id_str`.

The following python script then looks through all these numbers and for each one searches the JSON file for objects that contain that number and outputs them together in a list:

```
import gzip
import json

# Iterate over file of ids that appear both as tweet ids and reply to tweet ids
for idee in open('matching_numbers.files', 'r'):
    # remove quotes and convert to integer
    idee = int(idee[1:-2]) 
    # make list into which all Tweets from a conversation will go
    convo = [] 
    #iterate over all tweets
    with gzip.open('tweet_data.json.gz') as inputs:
        for line_no, line in enumerate(inputs):
            # use try, except to ignore incorrectly formatted lines 
            try: 
                tweet = json.loads(line) 
                if idee == tweet['id'] or idee == tweet['in_reply_to_status_id']:
                    # if we have a match, add this to the conversation list
                    convo.append(tweet)
                    print convo
            except:
                continue
```

This works producing lists of related Tweets, but is *extremely* slow, uses a lot of CPU power and also results in angry emails from the administrator of the server on which the json files are stored.

There are about 9000 id numbers in the `matching_numbers` file so this requires 9000 iterations of the 1.8GB file, which is a lot of data.

Is there a more efficient way to match these numbers?

I'm new to programming in general, and only know a little bit of python. I can't see any logical way of doing it without going through the whole file for each number. But maybe there is some other way?

Comment: In short: put the numbers in `matching_numbers` in a set, iterate over the JSON file with the tweets once and whenever you hit a relevant tweet put it in a dictionary with the id as the key.  You can then easily reconstruct the threads from the in-memory dictionary.

Comment: This works @SvenMarnach. Thanks a lot.